# Google Sheet Spreadsheet-Based Triggers Stopped Working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Today, the spreadsheet-based triggers on two of my Google Sheet projects stopped working.  These projects have been running smoothly for years, are completely unrelated and have not been recently updated.  I examined one of them and found the code targeted by the trigger to be working fine.  I unregistered the trigger and re-registered it to no avail.  There are no related errors logged in the Stack Logger. I created a new Google Sheet and created some spreadsheet-based triggers for it. They worked as usual.  What might be happening?

Comment: Might have something to do with [this](https://developers.google.com/terms/api-services-user-data-policy).

Comment: What does your [execution transcript](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#execution_transcript) say?

Comment: The  execution transcript does not saying anything since the problem is that the triggers refuse to fire.  The code is never run.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the triggers just started working again.  I will leave this up for a bit in case it is some help to others, who had the same issues.